# Windows message loop implementation in the Quake 2

Tags: c++, windows

I'm studing The `Quake 2` *source code*, for learning, getting experience and just for a pure pleasure. There is an entry point - the classic chunk of code - Windows msg loop. Here is what it look like:

```
while (1)
    {
        // if at a full screen console, don't update unless needed
        if (Minimized || (dedicated && dedicated->value) )
        {
            Sleep (1);
        }

        while (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            if (!GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                Com_Quit ();
            sys_msg_time = msg.time;
            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }

        do
        {
            newtime = Sys_Milliseconds ();
            time = newtime - oldtime;
        } while (time < 1);

        ...
        Qcommon_Frame (time);

        oldtime = newtime;
    }
```

I have some questions regarding the code above:

1.) What for is the line with `GetMessage` function:

```
if (!GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                Com_Quit ();
```

Shoud'nt it rather be just

```
if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                Com_Quit ();
```

???

2.) Why have we wait 1 m. sec in

```
do
    {
        newtime = Sys_Milliseconds ();
        time = newtime - oldtime;
    } while (time < 1);
```

?

Thx for help and suggestions.

Comment: 1) From the documentation on `GetMessage`: "If the function retrieves the `WM_QUIT` message, the return value is zero."

Comment: 2) I don't know why there's an artificial delay between frames. My guess would be, so that the game doesn't run too fast. I still remember the days when the new PCs (with CPU running at 40MHz) came with Turbo button on the front panel that switched the CPU to 20MHz, because otherwise many games were unplayable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, i understand, but what's the advantage of using  **GetMessage** instead of just simple "msg.message == WM_QUIT"?

Comment: What do you mean, instead of? The loop has to call `GetMessage` anyhow, to remove the message from the queue. A better question is, why they are passing `PM_NOREMOVE` to `PeekMessage` when they then turn around and remove the message right away. That I'm not sure - looks redundant to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think i get it - the GetMessage is necessary just becouse of the PM_NOREMOVE flag. The PeekMessage just check if there is a message and next the GetMessage REMOVES it from the queue. I thinks that it works like that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What do You think, if i'm right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As pointed out in the comments, the check for `!GetMessage` is equivalent to checking for `msg.msg==WM_QUIT`
2. That time check is in milliseconds, not seconds.  There's a possibility of a divide by zero error if any code attempts to normalize a point based on division by time.  Such could easily happen if the game was running as a dedicated server with no graphics or v-sync was turned off.  You could say the game is capped at 1000 frames/second.

Comment: Can You be so nice and explain shortly how the game's object  distance can be calculated an what's the formula `distance=rate/time` do? Some Example?

Comment: **I goofed up big on that one!**  The distance formula is `d = r * t`, not `d = r/t`.  Brain fart.  I'll stick with my answer. If the game attempts to divide anything based on time, zero wouldn't be a good value to divide by.  When I worked in a game studio (past tense - for what should be obvious reasons!), we had some "first frame" and "second frame" logic based on in game scenarios that assumed stuff was moving between frames.  I could see that code causing weird bugs if the rest of the items positions and collision state didn't change.